# Integral minimization

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

For the following integral the parameters *a* and *b* should be found, such that the value of the integral is minimal.

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx (f(x) - a \cdot cos(3x) - b \cdot sin(4x))^2$$

How can I do that?

Thanks

EDIT: $$f(x)=\pi - |x|$$

Comment: Compute the integral as an explicit function $g(a,b)$ and solve $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial b}=0.$$

Comment: Since $f(x)$ is an even function, we know in advance that the minimum is achieved at $b=0$, hence by Parseval's theorem the optimal $a$ is given by the coefficient of $\cos(3x)$ in the Fourier cosine series of $f(x)$ over $(-\pi,\pi)$, that is $\frac{4}{9\pi}$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to solve the following system:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{D}_\text{a}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{a}}\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\pi-\left|x\right|-\text{a}\cdot\cos\left(3x\right)-\text{b}\cdot\sin\left(4x\right)\right)^2\space\text{d}x\right)=0\\
\text{D}_\text{b}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\text{b}}\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\pi-\left|x\right|-\text{a}\cdot\cos\left(3x\right)-\text{b}\cdot\sin\left(4x\right)\right)^2\space\text{d}x\right)=0
\end{cases}
$$

Use:

1. $$\text{D}_\text{a}=\frac{18\text{a}\pi-8}{9}=0\Longleftrightarrow\text{a}=\frac{4}{9\pi}$$
2. $$\text{D}_\text{b}=2\text{b}\pi=0\Longleftrightarrow\text{b}=0$$